# How to integrate OnePay in an APP-TO-APP way with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to integrate OnePay in my Flutter App at the moment I have a web-view which returns an 'intent' as follows:

**`intent://#Intent;scheme=ewallet;action=cl.transbank.onepay.BROWSER_ACTION;package=cl.transbank.onepay;S.occ=21034545458949859339933;S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=cl.transbank.onepay;end`**

Using that Intent I have to open the OnePay app and make the payment, close go back to my flutter app, and check the status of my order.

Has anyone implemented this?
Or do you know a way to do it?